# How can I average a subset of an array and store the result in another array?

Tags: c, arrays, math, arduino, average

I have a C array `fftArray[64]` that contains values that I want averaged and placed into another array `frequencyBar[8]`. Getting the average of the entire array would be easy enough using a for statement.

```
int average, sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
     sum += fftArray[i];
}
average = sum/64;
```

But I just can't seem to figure out how to get the average from `fftArray[0]` through `fftArray[8]` and store this in `frequencyBar[0]`, the average of `fftArray[9]` through `fftArray[16]` and store this in `frequencyBar[1]`, etc. Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a homework assignment, so, rather than give you the outright answer, I'd rather just point you in the right direction...

use a nested loop (one inside the other).  One loop cycles 0-7, the other one 0 - 63.  Use the smaller one to populate your sliced averages.

or better yet use the % operator to see when you've gone through 8 elements and do an average of your total, then reset the total for the next set.  Then you'll have learned how to use the % operator too! :)

[EDIT]
ok, if not homework then something like this... I haven't written C in 5 years, so treat this as pseudo code:

```
//assuming you have a fftArray[64] with data, as per your question
int i,sum,avCounter,total;
int averages[8]; 
for(i=0 , avCounter=0, total=0 ; i<64; ){
    total += fftArray[i];
    if(++i % 8 == 0){   //%gives you the remainder which will be 0 every 8th cycle
      averages[avCounter++] = total / 8
      total = 0;  //reset for next cycle
    }
}
```

I think this will work better than a nested loop... but I'm not sure since % is division which is more processor heavy than addition... however... I doubt anyone would notice :)

Comment: I'm using this with my Arduino and an FFT library to extract frequency amounts from an audio signal to create an Arduino music visualizer. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Thanks Dr. Dredel. I'll try this and a nested statement and see which is faster. Clever use of %!

Comment: If you change the type of `i` to `unsigned`, then the compiler will be able to do the `i % 8` with a logical AND rather than a division.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        sum += fftArray[ 8*i + j ];
    }
    frequencyBar[i] = sum / 8;
}
```

Bonus exercise: Optimize this code for speed on your chosen platform.

Comment: Thanks, look like what I need. And I'll try to squeeze every ounce of performance from this, since the FFT algorithm takes a lot out of my little Arduino!

Answer (score 2):

TF,

**DISCLAIMER:** This code is just off the top of my head... it hasn't even been compiled, let alone tested.

```
// returns the average of array[first..last] inclusive.
int average(int[] array, int first, int last) {
    int sum = 0; 
    for (i = first; i <= last; i++)
        sum += array[i];
    return sum / (last - first + 1); // not sure about the +1
}
```

Then what you'd do is loop through the indexes of your `frequencyBar` array [0..7], setting `frequencyBar[i] = average(array, first, last);`... the tricky bit is calculating the `first` and `last` indexes... try `i*8` and `(i+1)*8` respectively... that may not be exactly right, but it'll be close ;-)

Cheers. Keith.

---

**EDIT:** Bored... waiting for my test results to come back. No news is good news, right? ;-)

It turns out that passing the `length` is a fair bit simpler than passing the `last` index.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int array[], int first, int length) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = first; i < first+length; i++)
        sum += array[i];
    return sum;
} 

double average(int array[], int first, int length) {
    double total = sum(array, first, length);
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("DEBUG: [%2d..%2d] %d", first, first+length-1, array[first]);
    for (int i = first+1; i < first+length; i++)
        printf(" + %d", array[i]);
    printf(" = %d / %d = %f\n", (int)total, length, total/length);
#endif
    return total / length;
} 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int array[] = {             // average
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, // 2.625 
        4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, // 3.125 
        2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, // 3
        5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, // 2.875
        3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, // 3.375
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, // 2.625
        4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, // 3.125
        2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4  // 3
    };
    double frequency[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        frequency[i] = average(array, i*8, 8);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        printf("%f ", frequency[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch your `sum` doesn't wrap around if `fftArray` has large value in!